# No databases are available. Permissions could be missing

Tags: hive, apache-sentry

I installed and configured sentry for hive. However, I keep getting :

`No databases are available.Permissions could be missing` in hive editor. I have created  `role` and `permission` for the user that I used to login into the hue but it does not help at all. Why is it?What could be the reason ? All I see is server1 and nothing else

I tried using  user`hue` that belongs to default group in hue.
Also, created a user 'hive' and a group 'hive' and assigned it to the grou, created a role but yet nothing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem: [link to the solution](http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/no-databases-available-permissions-missing-error-hive-sentry/)